# Travis Build failing for docker push

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to create a docker image and push it to dockerhub. Heres my link to the travis build

https://travis-ci.org/dhananjay12/games/jobs/462154006

Error:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake- 12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Usually, this error occurs because of invalid .travis.yml file, but I am not able to figure it out what's wrong in the file. Here is the link to my travis file:
https://github.com/dhananjay12/games/blob/master/.travis.yml

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because the default language falls back to Ruby.

Added the default language to be Java.

Although The project is having java,node,angular subprojects.